# How to apply merge logic in merge sort after splitting a collection?

Tags: algorithm, scala, mergesort

I am trying to sort an array using merge sort technique & below is the code I have written for that:

```
object MergeSort {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val arr = Array[Int](2,4,1,6,8,5,3,7)
        val b = mergeSort(arr)
        b.foreach(println)
    }

    def mergeSort(arr:Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {
        if(arr.length<2) arr
        else {
            val mid   = (arr.length)/2
            val (left,right)  = arr.splitAt(mid)
            println("Left: " + left.mkString(", "))
            println("right: "+ right.mkString(", "))
            mergeSort(left)
            mergeSort(right)
            merge(left, right, arr)
        }
    }

    def merge(left: Array[Int], right: Array[Int], arr: Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {
        var brr = new Array[Int](arr.length)
        val nl  = left.length
        val nr  = right.length
        var (i:Int,j:Int,k:Int) = (0,0,0)
        while(i < nl && j < nr) {
            if(left(i) < right(j)) {
                brr(k) = left(i)
                i += 1
            }
            else {
                brr(k) = right(j)
                j += 1
            }
            k+=1
        }
        while(i < nl) {
            brr(k) = left(i)
            i += 1
            k += 1
        }
        while(j < nr) {
            brr(k) = right(j)
            j += 1
            k += 1
        }
        brr
    }
}
```

I printed the statements where the main array is split into multiple smaller ones.
Output of  `println("Left: " + left.mkString(", ")` & `println("right: "+ right.mkString(", "))`

```
Left: 2, 4, 1, 6
right: 8, 5, 3, 7
Left: 2, 4
right: 1, 6
Left: 2
right: 4
Left: 1
right: 6
Left: 8, 5
right: 3, 7
Left: 8
right: 5
Left: 3
right: 7
```

The splitting mechanism is working as expected but the final output is not sorted as it prints the elements in the same order of input array: `arr = Array[Int](2,4,1,6,8,5,3,7)`
The code first gave `ArrayOutOfBoundException` at the line `brr(k) = left(i)` so I initialized the length of `brr` as `var brr = new Array[Int](arr.length)`
I couldn't trace why the output is not being sorted ? Could anyone let me know if I have missed to handle any case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `merge` method - here you create a temporary array `brr` which you set with `left` and `right` values. However, this `brr` is not used anywhere after the method returns. Instead, you should just use the original array `arr` that you pass to this method so that it gets updated with sorted values. So, the code should look as below:

```
...
def merge(left: Array[Int], right: Array[Int], arr: Array[Int]):Array[Int] = {
    val nl  = left.length
    val nr  = right.length
    var (i:Int,j:Int,k:Int) = (0,0,0)
    while(i < nl && j < nr) {
        if(left(i) < right(j)) {
            arr(k) = left(i)
            i += 1
        }
        else {
            arr(k) = right(j)
            j += 1
        }
        k+=1
    }
    while(i < nl) {
        arr(k) = left(i)
        i += 1
        k += 1
    }
    while(j < nr) {
        arr(k) = right(j)
        j += 1
        k += 1
    }
    arr
}
...
```

**Output**

```
Left: 2, 4, 1, 6
right: 8, 5, 3, 7
Left: 2, 4
right: 1, 6
Left: 2
right: 4
Left: 1
right: 6
Left: 8, 5
right: 3, 7
Left: 8
right: 5
Left: 3
right: 7
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```